# Returning comments from Graph API without pagination

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I own a private group on Facebook and am using the Graph API to extract the feed and write it to an external database for advanced analysis. This mostly works fine except when the comments on a post exceed 25. At that point, the JSON results return a pagination link and my script blows up.

Switching to comments of a post also paginates so that isn't a solution.

Are there any permissions or query variables I can use to force the pagination to happen at a different point, say 50 instead of 25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `.limit(n)` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4

Comment: I'm not sure .limit(n) is the solution here.  Using https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/TheGroup/feed/&access_token=TheToken&fields=comments.limit(50) still returns a paginated list...

Comment: limit is always applied, and 25 is the default value. So ideally your script needs to know how to handle pagination correctly. Alternatively, you can set limit to a reasonably large number so you can assume pagination isn't needed most of the time. In terms of JSON, the `paging` field will always appear containing `cursors`. However if pagination is not needed, then it won't contain `previous` nor `next` fields so you can ignore it.